# Change single database directory MySQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Is it possible to change a single database physical location? I want to dedicate an entire disk to this database.

MySQL community server version 5.7.14

Ubuntu Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: On the same server/port as other db's but in separate mount, stock server without a recompile, no

Comment: Is it possible in non stock server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Drew commented, different mount